# Cannot link with glfw3.lib c++

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, glfw, .lib

I am trying to compile a c++ file on command line with `g++`
i have this file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "C:\Users\Shaurya\Documents\Opengl\Dependencies\GLFW\include\GLFW\glfw3.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    GLFWwindow* window;
    if(!glfwInit()){
        cout << "Window not initialized";
        return -1;
    }
    window = glfwCreateWindow(600,600,"OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if(!window){
        cout << "Window Not created";
        glfwTerminate();
    }   
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    while(glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I run this command 
`g++ -o Test main.cpp -L <fullpath>\Dependencies\GLFW\lib-vc2019 -lglfw3.lib` 
but this throws a gigantic error

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: mode i386pe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o
C:\Users\Shaurya\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxDP2Km.o
(c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/libstdc++.dll.a)d004332.o
.
.
(c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/libgcc_s.a)d000122.o
(c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/libgcc.a)_chkstk_ms.o
(c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/libgcc.a)_ctors.o
(c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingwex.a)fesetenv.o
.
.
.
(c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmoldname.a)dagwbt.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtend.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It took me alot of time to realize that the `-l` is only looking for `.o` files
**So how do i link with .lib files?** i got the .lib from glfw.org binaries.
I dont want to use Visual Studio 2019 to do this because my laptop has a hard time running that.

Comment: Drop the `.lib` extension, just use `-lglfw3` as the option. If the library is installed (for GCC and MinGW) in a standard path (or a path added with `-L`) it should be found.

Comment: @Gal since a few days ago i was using the same files in visual studio and they were working

Comment: Visual Studio uses a different linker than GCC. They use different library formats.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i havent "installed" the library , i just picked it up from the lib vc 2019 folder from the downloaded folder and placed it in my project structure , to which i provide a link in the command. :(

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so.. i should be looking for glfw3.a? where?

Comment: Then you need to find the files built for MinGW, and "install" it. The MinGW package manager should probably have it in its repositories.

Comment: @Gal im using windows.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how do i install the .a file in windows?

Comment: If MinGW doesn't have it as a ready package to install (read the MinGW documentaiton about how to install packages), you download an archive built for MinGW and Windows, and copy the files in the archive to a suitable location on your system. Then use the `-I` (upper-case i)` option to point to where the header files are located, and `-L` to point to where the library files are located. And link with `-lglfw3` (that's lower-case L), without any prefix or suffix.

Comment: Your task would be easier if you switched to using msys2 and its more recent mingw and package management. https://www.msys2.org/ glfw is a package: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw) and the 64 bit version can be installed with this command from the msys2 shell: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved this. First i was using the wrong libraries. I was provided with multiple versions of Libraries and i was using VC version. But when i used MinGW Version , it worked.

Moreover , i was using relative paths without typing `./` before them.